# search and count letter by pointer C++

Tags: c++, pointers, search, char, counter

**i have a function**

1. `letter_counting(char * s1,char letter)`

i want send to function sentence and the user enter letter

the function must be search and count letter how many times it appears in the sentence**

**use pointer do not use dynamic memory**

this the all code

```
#include "letter_count.h"

letter_count::letter_count()
{
counter = 0;
}

void letter_count::Set_count(int Count)
{
counter = Count;
}
int letter_count::Get_count()
{
return counter;
}
void letter_count::letter_counting(char * s1,char letter)
{
//help me here.
}
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Have you tryed to implement something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example the member function can be defined like

```
void letter_count::letter_counting( const char *s1, char letter )
{
   for ( ; *st; ++st )
   {
      if ( *st == letter ) ++counter;
   }
}
```

or

```
void letter_count::letter_counting( const char *s1, char letter )
{
   for ( ; *st; ++st )
   {
      counter += *st == letter;
   }
}
```

or

```
void letter_count::letter_counting( const char *s1, char letter )
{
   while ( *st )
   {
      counter += *st++ == letter;
   }
}
```

and so on including standard algorithm `std::count`

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you're playing with objects in so simple case. If I were you, I'd write:

```
unsigned letter_count(const char*const text, const char letter){
    unsigned counter=0;
    for(unsigned i=0; text[i]!='\0'; ++i)
        if(text[i]==letter)
            ++counter;
    return counter;
}
```

Or, if you prefer pointers:

```
unsigned letter_count(char*const text, const char letter){
    unsigned counter=0;
    for(; *text!='\0'; ++text)
        if(*text==letter)
            ++counter;
    return counter;
}
```

Also, in each case I'd recomend you to write additional function to deal with `std::string` easily:

```
inline unsigned letter_count(const std::string& text, const char letter){
    return letter_count(text.c_str(), letter);
}
```

If some comments about code would be encouraged, please tell me what do you think I should comment.